# T-SQL AVG rounding a float result

Tags: t-sql, floating-point, average, rounding

I have a big stored procedure, with some nested cursors fetching some parameters dynamically. In this part I get the problem:

`DECLARE @Avg_Dev float;`

```
SET @sqlstatement = 'SELECT @Avg_Dev = AVG([' + @QLabel + '])
                    FROM Imported_Data
                    WHERE BrandID = ''' + CAST(@BrandID AS nvarchar(max)) + ''' AND CountryID = ''' + CAST(@CountryID AS nvarchar(max))
                    + ''' AND [Year] = ''' + CAST(@Year AS nvarchar(max))
                    + ''' AND ' + CAST(@QLabel AS nvarchar(max)) + ' <> ''' + CAST(@NoAnswer AS nvarchar(max)) + ''' ' + @Query;
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstatement, N'@Avg_Dev float output', @Avg_Dev output;
PRINT 'AVG Check'; PRINT @Avg_Dev;
```

`@BrandID` and `@CountryID` are `GUID`, `@Year` is `int`, `@QLabel` is `int` and `@Query` is `nvarchar(max)`. `@NoAnswer` contains a special value that has not to be considered.

`@QLabel` contains the column that I'm processing.
`@Query` contains a condition to apply to the *where* statement, and it's different for every `@QLabel`.

The problem is that @Avg_Dev always contains values rounded to the nearest integer, and I can't see why. `@QLabel` can be a value between 1 and 10.

I know this is not easy to read, but I didn't find any other way to process the table dynamically with every parameter changing often.

Comment: Can you include a print @sqlstatement so we can see the sql without the dynamic portions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the column (QLabel) is defined as an integer. So an AVG() would return an integer (ignoring the decimals) and pushing that into your float variable. Try this:

```
SET @sqlstatement = 'SELECT @Avg_Dev = AVG(convert(float,[' + @QLabel + '])) 
                    FROM Imported_Data 
                    WHERE BrandID = ''' + CAST(@BrandID AS nvarchar(max)) + ''' AND CountryID = ''' + CAST(@CountryID AS nvarchar(max)) 
                    + ''' AND [Year] = ''' + CAST(@Year AS nvarchar(max))
                    + ''' AND ' + CAST(@QLabel AS nvarchar(max)) + ' <> ''' + CAST(@NoAnswer AS nvarchar(max)) + ''' ' + @Query;
```

Comment: Sweet, glad I could help